# How to embed a library JAR in an OSGi bundle using Tycho

Tags: maven, jar, osgi, dependency-management, tycho

I am using Maven with the Tycho plugin to build my OSGi bundles. 
In one of my bundles, I use the facebook API through the restfb-1.7.0.jar library.

For now, it is directly placed on the classpath (in Eclipse) and embedded in the effective OSGi bundle jar file with following build.properties configuration:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
           .,\
           lib/restfb-1.7.0.jar
```

Now I would like to have this restfb lib downloaded from Maven (e.g. as dependency) and embedded into my OSGi bundle jar. Is it possible with Maven/Tycho? How?

Answer (score 18):

You need the following configuration to embed a JAR into an OSGi plugin with Tycho:

1. In the pom.xml, configure the `copy` goal of the `maven-dependency-plugin`

   ```
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.10</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>copy-libraries</id>
                       <phase>validate</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>copy</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <artifactItems>
                               <item>
                                   <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
                                   <version>1.7.0</version>
                               </item>
                           </artifactItems>
                           <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                           <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                           <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                           <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
2. Edit the MANIFEST.MF to have the library added to the OSGi bundle classpath

   ```
   Bundle-ClassPath: ., lib/restfb.jar
   ```
3. Edit the build.properties to have the library included in the JAR packaged by Tycho

   ```
   bin.includes = META-INF/,\
                  .,\
                  lib/restfb.jar
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you would want is to have a dependency in the POM with the compile time scope like the example below: use the correct artifact and version info to get the item you want.  you should investigate the dependencies section of the maven ref for poms

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```